# How to make a tooltip on a image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find something to make a tooltip on a image.

For example:
[image]

I don't know how can I make one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` have a Tooltip property

[MSDN entry for asp:Image control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx)^

```
<asp:Image AlternateText="string" CssClass="string" ID="string" runat="server" ToolTip="string"/>
```

Otherwise, `alt` property of the html image control act like a tooltip